# application deployed on jboss doesn't update db schema

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, datasource, hbm2ddl

I started to study j2ee and looked into jboss7 quickstarts. To be exact jboss-as-login example. It works nice but when i change default datasource (with newly created one) and persistence.xml it doesn't update db schema with hbm2ddl despite of property set in persistence.xml. And there is **no signs** of updating in log

here are my files

persistence.xml - http://pastebin.com/2M5gx0Tp
startup log - http://pastebin.com/U0zZVQn0

i would say that if i change something in entities code and then manually correct database everything works. But i don't want to create everything by hand.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the property be called `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`? In your configuration you refer to it as `hbm2ddl.auto`.